# Error bars when the variables are related

Tags: confidence-interval

I am a stats novice so I'm sorry if my jargon is a bit off.

I have several large samples of workers in different demographic categories from two different fields A and B.  I want to compare the proportion of people in each sample (not of equal size) and try to figure out if there is a difference in the distributions the samples were drawn from.

I computed the average percentage of workers in each demographic category for field A and field B.  However, I wanted to construct error bars for my estimates.

I realize that because I am dealing with percentages, the values in each category are all related.  If one of the values is larger, the others must be small and so on.

Does this affect the confidence intervals? Does it make sense to just compute the standard deviation of all "older males in field A" for instance and use that for my error bar?

Comment: It seems I have misinterpreted your question, thus I deleted my previous answer. To me standard deviations of binary variables make little sense, and demographic categories seem to be nothing else than dichotomous variables that equal 1 in case an individual is in this group and 0 otherwise. Reporting such standard errors seems pointless, as it is always $p(1-p)$. However, if you take a look at how the chi-square test works, deviation from expected distribution relative to sample size is the key feature.

Comment: Errm, not quite.  The variance of a binary variable $Z$ is indeed $p(1-p)$ but the variance of the estimate of $p$ isn't because it depends on the sample size.  More data makes you less uncertain about what $p$ is.  But regardless of one feels about binary variables, $p$ isn't one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a very good point: the estimates of the percentages in different categories are correlated. In fact, if categories $i$ and $j$ have true probabilities of $p_i$ and $p_j$, then the estimated probabilities will have a correlation of $-\sqrt{\frac{p_i p_j}{(1-p_i)(1-p_j)}}$.

This, however, does not affect the marginal variability of each particular estimate. So one usually presents regular standard errors. You can show regular confidence intervals as well as long as you are clear that those are not simultaneous confidence intervals. As you go deeper into the analysis, then depending on the questions you want answered, the presence of correlation might have to be taken into account.

Comment: My question is sort of awkward, but I want to know how to construct 'simultaneous confidence intervals' if possible.